# restrict the pointers in structures

Tags: c, pointers, structure

```
struct a {
   int *p;
   int c;
} a1,a2;

void fun(struct a);

int main()
{

    a1.p=malloc(4);
    *(a1.p)=10;
    a1.c=20;

    fun(a1);
    printf("%d\n",*(a1.p));
    return 0;
}

void fun(struct a temp)
{   
    a2=temp;
    *(a2.p)=30;
    printf("%d\n",*(a2.p));
}
```

I have a program like this and now my question is....
   when we assign the *(a2.p)=30; that will affects the *(a1.p) value How would you avoid?i.e, even though i changed the *(a2.p) value but i don't want to affect *(a1.p) value How would ypu do it? please suggest me

Thanks in advance

Comment: "*How would you avoid?.* Do not do `a2=temp;` or `fun(a1);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
a2.p = malloc( sizeof( int ) ); // << Note this.

if ( a2.p == NULL ) {
  // We ran out of memory in the memory pool. Do some error handling.
}

*( a2.p ) = 30;
```

... note that `a1.p` and `a2.p` both point to the same block of memory. Hence, change where `a2.p` points before mutating its value.

**Aside:**

- Do not `malloc` a fixed size (your `malloc( 4 )` should be `malloc( sizeof( int ) )`).

Comment: Thanks boss after i posted this question i got same idea anyway Thanks a lot.....